# Multiple Queries Express/Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, express, ejs

I am using Express/Ejs/Node/Mongodb
I have multiple models Im querying through and three different data sets to do stuff with.
I need to have a function that calculates the average pain level on symptoms & counts the bodyparts most logged.
I don't know how to simplify my route below and attach these functions to them and send them back to the front end to do something with.
Also any good reads on this particular problem.

**My route looks like this**

```
app.get('/dashboard', isLoggedIn, (req, res) =>{
    let thirtyDays = moment().subtract(30, 'd').format('YYYY-MM-DD')
    SymptomModel.find({postedBy : req.user._id, created: {$gte: `${thirtyDays}`} }, function(error, results){
        if(error){
            console.log('Error: ', error)
        } else {
            console.log('Found all symptoms from past 30da: ', results)
        }
    })

    TreatmentModel.find({postedBy : req.user._id, created: {$gte: `${thirtyDays}`} }, function(error, results){
        if(error){
            console.log('Error: ', error)
        } else {
            console.log('Found all Treatments from past 30da:', results)
        }
    })

    DoctorModel.find({postedBy : req.user._id, created: {$gte: `${thirtyDays}`} }, function(error, results){
        if(error){
            console.log('Error: ', error)
        } else {
            console.log('Found all Doctors from past 30da: ', results)
        }
    })
    res.render('dashboard.ejs', {
        user: req.user.firstName,
        data: `I would be for the last 30 days from ${now}`,
        test: "I need this to be the data"

    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to get multiple data sets with the following code after researching and trying more.

I wanted to post this as a response to my question in case anyone else came upon it.
If you have and better suggestions on how to do this I am open to feedback.

```
app.get('/dashboard', isLoggedIn, async (req, res) =>{
    let thirtyDays = moment().subtract(30, 'd').format('YYYY-MM-DD')
    const doctorData = await DoctorModel.find({postedBy : req.user._id, created: {$gte: `${thirtyDays}`} }) 
    const treatmentData = await TreatmentModel.find({postedBy : req.user._id, created: {$gte: `${thirtyDays}`} }) 
    //const symptomData = await      SymptomModel.find({postedBy : req.user._id, created: {$gte: `${thirtyDays}`} })
    SymptomModel.find({postedBy : req.user._id, created: {$gte: `${thirtyDays}`} })
        .then(symptomData => {
            res.render('dashboard.ejs', {
                doctor: doctorData,
                symptom: symptomData,
                treatment: treatmentData,
                user: req.user.firstName
            });
        })


        });//closes route //req res function
```